# How to check if moving a file is finished in perl?

Tags: perl, file-moving

I have a Perl script that moves files into folders. Every time it runs it checks the filenames in the folders. But if I have a bigger file it might not be ready with the moving when it checks the filenames, and it really can mess up stuff. I would like to stop at the end of the loop and check that the moving is finished, before it continues.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: you could probably check whether the file exists in the new location after the loop.

Comment: It's too vague to give you an answer. What you need is some sort of lock mechanism, like `flock` -

Comment: Is the problem that you are seeing a partial file? If so, move using `rename` since it happens atomically. If you can't use `rename`, `move` the file to a temporary directory from which you can `rename`, then use `rename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three common approaches.

1. Monitor the file size. Assume the file is complete when the size hasn't changed for X seconds. Non-trivial to implement and prone to errors.
2. Upload a marker file **after** the moved file is complete. Check for the existence of the marker rather than the original file.
3. Copy the file using a different name. Rename it once the transfer is complete.

Comment: Yes. Move the file to `your_file_name.in_progress`. When the move has finished, rename it to `your_file_name`. Note that moves as long as you're on the same file system are usually pretty much instantaneous - as it's just updating the directory table rather than actually moving data around.

Answer (score 0):

```
sleep 1 while -e $original_filename;
```

There are numerous options and even an infinite while option, but you need to format the code in order to ensure you do not put the script in a permanent loop if the file will never exist.

Comment: That's not as good as it sounds - a really large file will exist, but only be partially written.

Comment: @TheAdam, Correct yes. I updated it to instead test original file